# Is passing html with ajax in json format is right practice?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am working on an event scheduling project and replace calendar HTML whenever some operation is done e.g. add event or change date.

My code:

```
$(document).on("change", "#datepicker1", function() {

  var datepicker1 = $("#datepicker1").val();

  if (datepicker1 != "") {
    $.ajax({

      url: url,
      type: "post",
      data: {
        date: datepicker1
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {

        $("#reservation-content").html(data.html);

        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);

      }

    });
  }
});
```

Is passing HTML with ajax as JSON is the right practice. If no, then what is right way to change calendar content?

Comment: It is not really possible to tell whether this is the correct approach or not. Passing HTML using JSON from one end to the other itself is completely fine. If this is the correct approach in your case, maybe. But if you build a complex project where the UI changes based on data/state then a better choice might be using vuejs, svelte, react or angular.

Comment: @t.niese: I am working on event scheduling project in PHP and also use setInterval method which checks for change after every 5 seconds. I wonder it may cause memory issues of DOM and my page may be getting slow. That's why I ask this question if there are options to make may code efficient.

Comment: Your comment asks something different/additional then your original "question" does. However, this does not change anything I have written before. Well, except that polling (especially with intervals) is always the worst method to check for updates (there are various topics here on SO about that), but if you implement your project with PHP then you likely need to stick with it.

Comment: @t.niese: You said that passing HTML using JSON from one end to the other itself is completely fine. I wonder it may slow my page when html will be replaced with new html after each event trigger e.g add, delete. Tell me if i am wrong. But if i am right, is there any way to minimize html code in response or other way to optimize my page performance.

Comment: I feel like I repeat myself. It is not possible to tell with the given information. Each method will manipulate the DOM and/or HTML because otherwise, they could not update the displayed content. So whether the performance will be bad or not depends on how the given method is used.